# How to process Every Item In a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hi all I'm trying to extract text from several websites
everything works ok but when I run the script I only extract one website
from the domain (list) that I created which has 3 websites 
what I'm doing it wrong i need to extract all the domian items to a file

Thanks

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib3
import certifi

http = urllib3.PoolManager(
    cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
    ca_certs=certifi.where())

domain =('https://www.betfair.com/exchange/', 'https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html','https://anaconda.org/pypi/urllib3')
for url in domain:
    page = requests.get(url, verify=True)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    content = (soup.get_text().encode('utf-8'))
    with open("article.txt", "w") as wa, open("article.txt", "r") as ra, open('outfile.txt', "w") as outfile:
        wa.write(content)
        for line in ra:
            if not line.strip(): continue
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: I think you're overwriting previous info each time since you have the "w" when opening the file

Comment: It worked Thanks

Comment: Also, you're setting domain up as a tuple rather than a list. You want '['s  rather than '(' when you're assigning domain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe that you are overwriting the file every time. That's why you should open the files in an append mode, like this:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'a'):
    ...
```

Hope it helps

Comment: But i think i need to clean the file every time i use the script